# Quotient of normalizers is the fixed points of a homogeneous space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, with subgroups $A \leqslant H$. Is there an isomorphism of $N_G A$-sets (or just sets)
$$ N_G A / N_H A  \cong (G/H)^A ?$$

This dropped out of some calculations of Mackey functors, but I would like a more direct proof (or a counterexample).

Comment: A priori (e.g, when $A=1$ and $H$ is not normal in $G$) $N_G(A)$ does not normalize $N_H(A)$. Are you assuming $H$ is normal in $G$? or in which sense do you mean an "isomorphism"?

Comment: @YCor, probably an isomorphism of sets with $N_GA$-action?

Comment: Is the following concrete re-formulation of the question correct?  "Do we have that the 'transporter' $\{g \in G : \operatorname{Int}(g)^{-1}A \subseteq H\}$ of $A$ into $H$ equals $N_G A\cdot H$?"

Comment: If so, then I think that $H = V_4$ (Klein 4-group), $G = V_4 \rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(V_4)$ its holomorph, and $A$ any of the order-2 subgroups is a counterexample; but maybe I miscalculated.

Comment: Another counterexample is $G=S_4$, $A=\langle(1,2)\rangle$, $H=\langle (1,2),(3,4)\rangle$.

Comment: You get a counterexample with $H=N_GA$ whenever a group $G$ has a subgroup $A$ such that some conjugate of $A$ is different from $A$ but normalized by $A$. Minimal counterexample: $G$ dihedral of order $8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false, as shown by the counter examples of LSpice and Neil Strickland.

Comment: Hi David, can you say anything about this counter example and provide a reference?

Comment: In general in a $G$-set $X$ the subset $X^A$ is preserved by the action of the subgroup $N_GA$, so $X^A$ can be considered as an $N_GA$-set.

Now let $p\in X$ have stabilizer $H$, and assume that $A\subset H$, so that $p\in X^A$.

The stabilizer of $p$ in the $N_GH$-set $X^A$ is $H\cap N_GA=N_HA$, so we get an isomorphism of $N_GH$-sets from $N_GA/N_HA$ to the orbit of $p$ in $X^A$. 

The question is whether, if the action of $G$ on $X$ is transitive, the action of $N_GH$ on $X^A$ is necessarily transitive, and the answer is no.

Comment: In Neil's counterexample $G=S_4$ is acting transitively on the set of all $2$-element subsets of {1,2,3,4}.

Comment: Would you tick your answer to avoid automatic bumping of the question?